# How to stop a function on mouseover in query?

Tags: jquery

I have my own created slider of jquery, it slides very well. the code of the slider is given below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var show_items = 3;
    for(var i=1; i<=show_items; i++)
    {
        $('#my_ul li:nth-child('+i+')').show();
    }
    function fade()
    {
        $('#my_ul li:first').delay(2000).animate({opacity: 0.2, width: "toggle"}, 1500);
    }
    fade();
    setInterval(function()
    {
        var last = $('#my_ul li:first').html();
        $('#my_ul li:first').remove();
        $('#my_ul').append('<li>'+last+'</li>');
        $('#my_ul li:nth-child('+show_items+')').fadeIn(1500);
        fade();
    }, 3500);

    $("#my_ul").mouseover(function() { 
        $(this).stop();
        return false;
    }); 

});


</script>
<style type="text/css">
#my_ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    width: 205px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="my_ul">
<li>
<div style="background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; margin-left: 5px;"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="background-color: blue; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; margin-left: 5px;"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="background-color: green; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; margin-left: 5px;"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="background-color: yellow; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; margin-left: 5px;"></div>
</li>
<li>
<div style="background-color: orange; width: 200px; height: 200px; float: left; margin-left: 5px;"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

But I want to stop or pause the slider on mouseover. The code I use to stop or pause is not working.
Please help me to sort it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$("#my_ul").mouseover(function(event) { 
        event.stopPropagation();        
    });
```

Comment: what is this "event"?

Comment: It is the eventObject, The event object is always passed to the handler and contains a lot of useful information what has happened.

Comment: As there is not default mouse over event for li items in any browser, just stopping the event will result in nothing actually.

Answer (score 0):

You use an interval for your main functionality, so you have to stop that interval using the [`clearInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) method. The expected parameter for this function is the interval id which is returned by `setInterval`.
Then, on `mouseout`, you have to create the interval again.

Comment: Can u give an example?

Comment: There are examples for everything at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp and http://api.jquery.com/hover/ I will not write your code. You have to put it together on your own.

Comment: i also want to stop function fade. how to do that?